# Need SQL Query to find exactly one record from table

Tags: database

```
booking id     booked_journey_info_id   PNR
1              1000                     PNR5000
1              1001                     PNR5000
1              1002                     PNR7000
1              1003                     PNR7000
```

In above table I want to retrieve exactly one record for each PNR. So for above case, for PNR - PNR5000 query should retrieve exact one booked_journey_info_id(1000 or 10001) and for PNR - PNR7000 query should retrieve exact one booked_journey_info_id(1002 or 10003).

I need only 1 record per PNR.

Comment: Please tag with the RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 1):

If it does not matter which `booked_journey_info_id` you get from the group, you can use the `max()` aggregate function to pull the max id:

```
SELECT MAX(booked_journey_info_id)
FROM myTbl GROUP BY PNR
```

Basically the aggregate function tells which value to pull from the group.

Comment: Thanks for the query, but i don't want to select PNR into the select clause. Without that is it possible to achieve the above result?

Comment: Yes, you just leave `PNR` out of the select cause. I updated my answer for ya.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler than [Shredder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11870076) is

```
select * from tablename group by PNR
```

This selects an arbitrary row, as (seemingly) desired.

Comment: @Shredder, yeah, it depends. I'd upvote your comment on the question if I could.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want complete rows.

The following should work in any database.

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select pnr, max(booked_journey_info_id) as maxid
      from t
      group by pnr
     ) tpnr
     on tpnr.maxid = t.booked_journey_info_id
```